# VBscript to delete multiple .txt files from a directory with 0kb size and with current date

Tags: vbscript

How can I have a VBscript to delete multiple `.txt` files from a directory with 0kb size and with current date?

Comment: What did you tried so far as code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a tested version and it should works for you ;)

```
Option Explicit
Dim fs, f, f1, D, MyDate
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFolder("E:\Test")
For Each f1 in f.files
    D = f1.DateLastModified
    MyDate = Split(D," ")
    If f1.size = 0 and Cdate(MyDate(LBound(MyDate))) = Date Then     
    fs.deletefile f1.path,true
End If
Next
Set fs = Nothing
Set f = Nothing
Set f1 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

After removing the fat of @Hackoo's and @legendjr code (variables used just once (no f, no chance of f.DeleteFile), camouflaged type conversions, [cargo cult Sets to Nothing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx)) and exploiting the fact that [Dates are Doubles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/eric-s-complete-guide-to-vt-date.aspx):

```
Option Explicit

Const csFolder = ".\30252843"

Dim dblToday : dblToday = Date()
Dim oFile
For Each oFile In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(csFolder).Files
    If 0 = oFile.Size And dblToday = Fix(oFile.DateLastModified) Then oFile.Delete True
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is a one-time cleanup, you could probably use Windows Explorer to filter the type, size, and date columns to find and delete it in one go.  If this is a recurring thing that needs a script, my first guess would be to do something like this:

```
Dim fs, f, f1
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFolder("C:\FolderPath")
For Each f1 in f.Files
    If f1.Size = 0 and f1.DateLastModified = Date Then
        f.DeleteFile
    End If
Next

Set fs = Nothing
Set f = Nothing
Set f1 = Nothing
```

I haven't tested this code yet, so I would try it out on a dummy location first.  I hope this helps.

Comment: First change to `For Each f1 in f.Files`, then test.

Comment: Second think about .DateLastModified having a specific time, Date having an implicit time of 00:00:00, and the semantics of `=`, then test.

Comment: True, you could wrap it in Day(f1.DateLastModified) = Day(Date) etc for month and year?

Comment: Third reflect upon whether folders have a .DeleteFile method and how to name variables properly, then **test**. By now you should be aware of the dangers of not tested code.